# Compiling java projects from other java projects

Tags: java, compilation

I am making a java project that creates other java code, and I need it to compile it, and I need it to work on a system whether or not it has a compiler installed natively. How would I go about this? I cannot use `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` from the `JavaCompiler` library, because I cannot just assume that the user has a java compiler on their system.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about implementing code from other projects in your current project, create a Java package.

Otherwise...

Assuming you are using eclipse

Step #1. Right Click => Project

Step #2. Click Project Properties

Step #3. Click on Java Build Path

Step #4. Click the Projects Tab

Step #5. Click the Add Button

Step #6. Select the Project you want to add

Step #7. Click OK button

Comment: Question says *"java project that **creates** other java code"*. This is not about multi-module projects, it's about a Java program that generates Java source files and then needs to compile them immediately, so the newly generated code can be executed immediately.